# android build.gradle.kts flavoured implementation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Im converting my `build.gradle` into `build.gradle.kts` DSL. So far the conversion was smooth. But im stuck when it comes to flavour dependency before in groovy I used :

```
nameofflavourImplementation  "some.dependency:1.0.0"
```

i read a lot about how to do this, no luck with this for example:

```
val nameofflavour by configurations.creating
nameofflavour(group="",name="some.dependency:1.0.0",ext = "aar")
```

this cause a compile error that the configuration is not known.

Im using gradle: 6.4.1

EDIT:

```
productFlavors {
    create("nameofflavour") {
        dimension = "full"
        applicationId = "com.someid.android"
    }
```

Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Can you add your code where you're declaring your flavours?

Comment: if added the missing part

Comment: Have you set `flavorDimensions("full")` above `productFlavors`?

Comment: yes. i have set them

Comment: Try `setDimension("full")` in `create()`

Comment: it's aready there, see initial question

Answer (score 18):

Since you're using `create("nameofflavour")`, `nameofflavour` is registered dynamically. So it needs to be in the scope before dependencies can be declared like this:

```
val nameofflavourImplementation by configurations
dependencies {
    nameofflavourImplementation("some.dependency:1.0.0")
}
```

**OR**

You can directly use it as a string:

```
dependencies {
    "nameofflavourImplementation"("some.dependency:1.0.0")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When using :

```
val nameofflavour by configurations

dependencies {
  ...
```

i get again a compile error: Configuration with name 'nameofflavour' not found.

Using the  "nameofflavourImplementation"("some.dependency:1.0.0") approach gives an Build Failure:

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:nameofflavourDebugCompileClasspath'.
```